# Use of Sqlite Stored Procedure in Android

Tags: android, stored-procedures, android-sqlite

I have read that we can not create Stored Procedure in SQLite, But I'd to know is there any third party library available by which we can use the same or any other way to create or call SQLITE Stored Procedure in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not support stored procedures. Neither in Android, nor in other environments. There has been efforts made to include stored procedures in SQLite like [this](https://github.com/wolfch/sqlite-3.7.3.p1) one, but these have been far from being perfect.

Reassess your needs for a stored procedure in a resource constrained environment such as Android, and see if you really need them. Stored procedures are better suited for those DB engines that run on a server platform.