# Stored Procedures for sqlite Windows Store Apps

Tags: sqlite, stored-procedures, windows-store-apps

As i have searched there are no ways to write stored procedures in sqlite,is there any alternative solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of Sqlite Stored Procedure in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436046/use-of-sqlite-stored-procedure-in-android)

Comment: You will have to implement a stored procedure within your accessing code, and make use of basic SQLite functionality (see reference documentation https://www.sqlite.org/about.html).  What do you want to do?